# Booting from flash drive

Tags: boot, flash, drive

Hello I'm rather new to Ubuntu and I was wondering if someone could point me to a tutorial of how to boot from a flash drive and tell me if I need to partition my hard drive in anyway in order to boot from a flash drive. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick . No, you don't need to partition harddrive. Use F12 or F9 depending on its BIOS then select USB device boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu pretty much will help you do all you need if you have successfully created a USB Bootable Ubuntu, and then changed the boot priority to boot from External/USB from the boot screen.

Follow these instruction to create the bootable USB:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Here you can find the instruction on how to change the priority from BIOS

1. Restart your computer.
2. Quickly press F2 or F12 or Del (depends on your machine)
3. If you can see the Bios screen go to boot.
4. From boot locate the priority order of your boot ex.(HDD, CD, USB)
5. Press + to change order and make USB first
6. Press f10 to save and exit or an equivalent key.
7. Make sure the usb is inserted and contains bootable Ubuntu.
8. Follow the installation instruction and make sure you install ubuntu without deleting Windows if this is what you want.

Check this link for a nice instructions from Ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

refer below tutorial link.

[Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from Ubuntu Live System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

you need bootable DVD of Ubuntu. This installer also provides option for saving settings changes to file.